# Pip Install hangs

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pip

I currently have Python 3.5 on my Windows machine. I'm trying to install a Python package using the command `"pip install"` but as soon as I hit enter nothing happens. The action hangs for such a long time and when I try to exit the command line, it freezes. How do I get pip install to work?

Comment: post contents of %HOME%\.pip\pip.log

Comment: You should try `py -3 -m pip install some_package_you_want`

Comment: A note to future visitors of this thread: first check the output of `pip -v install <package>`, maybe it doesn't hang, just takes unusually long (but actually does stuff in the background) -- this was the case for me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@JBernardo 's comment worked for me. Thanks!

```
python -m pip install some_package_you_want
```

Comment: and if you want more diagnostic cruft, `python -v -m pip install some_package_you_want`

Comment: try python -v -m pip install to see whats going on

Comment: this worked for me.  Any idea why this works?

Answer (score 71):

If you are you using WSL2, indeed it could be related to `pip` trying to connect to an XServer. If so, clearing the `DISPLAY` environment variable first before running it may help:

```
export DISPLAY=
pip install <packagename>
```

(Or, as a one-liner: `DISPLAY= pip install <packagename>`)

Comment: do you mean like this: `export DISPLAY= pip install django` ?

Comment: @flyingduck92 run the two commands separately. The export command just sets the DISPLAY environment variable to an empty string

Answer (score 16):

If you're using Ubuntu via WSL2 on Windows, it might not work outside a virtualenv.  `python3 -v -m pip install ...` showed me that it was hanging on some OS X keychain import...  Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: uh yes, start your xserver!

Comment: @pscheit would that fix it?

Comment: @JamesM.Lay yep this was my issue. It was waiting for a connection to the x server (i guess to show the prompt for the keychain password)

Comment: As another workaround, you can temporarily disable that prompt with `unset DISPLAY`.

Comment: whoa, that's wayyy simpler.

Comment: This work for me too, **but WHY????** I'm using X410 as an Xserver. Before that I tried `Pip`, `PDM`, `Pyenv` and Poetry with `<command> list` to list installed packages and took between 90 and 120 seconds

Comment: that's a real WTF imo - it should prompt on the command-line instead of opening a window on some display. thanks for your help!

Comment: `unset DISPLAY` is cool!

Answer (score 4):

I had to start 'Xlaunch' display server and it worked, according to a @pscheit it was waiting for a connection to x-server and launching one fixed it

Answer (score 2):

`pip install something` was hanging for me when I ssh'd into a linux machine and ran `pip install` from that shell. Using `-v` from above answers showed that this step was hanging

`import 'keyring.backends.macOS' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f3d15404d90>`

This popped up a keyring authentication window on the linux machine's desktop, waiting for my password. Typing my password allowed this to progress.

I have no idea why a macOS package was being imported on a linux machine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is connected to me using `apple silicon` but suddenly `pip install` stopped working. No error and nothing happened. Python reinstall didn't help, `venv` reinitialization didn't help.

The only thing that helped was restarting my machine. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pip` programmatically like shown below.

```
import pip

pip.main(['install', 'the_package_you_want_installed'])
```