# pip3 install pandas hangs

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to install pandas on the raspberry pi 2 (model b, 7 wheezy), python3.5.1, pip 9.0.1 with the command from the title, this is my terminal.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo pip3 install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-0.21.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas)
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Running setup.py install for pandas ... /
```

I have left it like this for hours, with no progress, what is wrong?

Without success, I have tried:

- [Pip Install hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925566/pip-install-hangs)
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174186

Edit in response to Andy K's comment, I have tried the following with apt-get:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pandas
```

I've added the correct [repositories](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository), but still no joy

Comment: @downvoter care to explain?

Comment: Have you tried that `sudo apt-get install python-pandas`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this by upgrading the os on the pi, then using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

My repositories are now slightly different to in the repositories [link](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository) in the question, they are below:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

If anyone's interested, the specs are now as below:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Finally, with the new os I still could not pip install pandas, i left it running overnight with no success

Comment: For whatever value, the Pandas install ran for a few minutes (RPi0W), then ceased showing progress, then hung so badly it disconnected my SSH session and hung the whole system. Using python3-pandas, it worked perfectly, and quickly.

Answer (score 5):

I've had this same issue on ARM machines using Docker. On my machine python3-pip provided an old pip distribution (9.0.1). So for me upgrading pip & setuptools sufficed

```
pip3 install -U pip setuptools
```

Then you can install the rest of your dependencies normally.

Comment: Weird, first it moved on from `Installing build dependencies` after collecting pandas, but when it got to numpy, it halted again. I'm considering a clean install.

Comment: sometimes it can depend on pandas version as well. you can try earlier versions of pandas and that may work

Comment: This worked for me. I am running Andronix modded Debian

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem on my venv and the solution was upgrade my pip3 version, by default my venv came with pip 18.1 and the actual is 21.3.1.

first i ran

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

after

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using NVIDIA Jetpack 4.6 on a Jetson Nano with Ubuntu 18.04. 'pip3 install --upgrade pandas' would just hang until I upgraded pip and setuptools. You'd think they'd ship a more recent version considering that Jetpack 4.6 just came out.