# On WSL2 `pip install virtualenv` comand hangs for too long

Tags: python, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-keyring

Under WSL2 running Ubuntu 20.04 I've tried to install virtualenv with pip running `pip install virtualenv` but the command just hangs printing nothing.

I terminated it and ran it again with `python3 -v -m pip install virtualenv` as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67744064/13789930) and it hangs on `import 'keyring.backends.OS_X'` line:

```
[...]
# /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/backends/__pycache__/_OS_X_API.cpython-38.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/backends/_OS_X_API.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/backends/__pycache__/_OS_X_API.cpython-38.pyc'
# destroy keyring.backends._OS_X_API
import 'keyring.backends.OS_X' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fa66c4b4610>
```

I've tried running `python -m pip install some_package_you_want` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33930410/13789930) but the same problem occurs.

Also, I've tried exporting `PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring` environment variable as advised [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9061#issuecomment-717721223) but unfortunately it did not solve the problem either.

EDIT: The `python3 -v -m pip install virtualenv` command eventually succeeded after hanging for about 5 minutes.

EDIT2: I think the problem is with the WSL2 being too slow as commented [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6643). Eventually I've installed the virtualenv (venv) with `sudo apt-get install python3-venv` and activated the virtual environment with `python3 -v -m venv venv` command and the similar hang problem occurred now on the line `import 'argparse' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7ff1bc5f1c40>` hanging here for about 2 minutes. This supports the WSL2 slowness problem.

Answer (score 40):

Is the `DISPLAY` environment variable set? If so, clearing it first before running pip worked for me:

```
export DISPLAY=
pip install <packagename>
```

(Or, as a one-liner: `DISPLAY= pip install <packagename>`)

Comment: Unfortunately, at the moment I cannot recreate the issue, so I'll leave the answer unaccepted. Maybe someone finds it useful.

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: @IvanVnucec You cannot recreate this issue, probably because you have your X server running. I can fix this issue by clearing DISPLAY or by starting X server on what DISPLAY points at.

Answer (score 2):

I traced the problem on my system down to [this line](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/b392833a0f1cff1bbee1ac6dbe0270cccdd0c11f/src/pip/_internal/network/auth.py#L29):

```py
import keyring
```

[Importing `keyring` taking very long in WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68369527) is an already known problem, that has been [fixed in keyring versions ≥ 21.6.0](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/issues/531).

Therefore, updating `keyring` to the latest version should solve the problem:

```
pip install -U keyring
```

or rather

```
DISPLAY= pip install -U keyring
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging with the logs, running `python3 -v -m pip install packageName` command for both display value set and display value empty. In case of display value empty, the following happens:

```
import 'jeepney.bus' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f8ee337f910>
# /home/shouv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jeepney/__pycache__/bus_messages.cpython-38.pyc matches /home/shouv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jeepney/bus_messages.py
# code object from '/home/shouv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jeepney/__pycache__/bus_messages.cpython-38.pyc'
# /home/shouv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jeepney/__pycache__/wrappers.cpython-38.pyc matches /home/shouv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jeepney/wrappers.py
# code object from '/home/shouv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jeepney/__pycache__/wrappers.cpython-38.pyc'
Collecting thing
  Downloading thing-0.3.3.tar.gz (12 kB)
Collecting mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108 kB)
import 'jeepney.wrappers' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f8ee338baf0>
```

But for display value set to something, the collecting of the package does not happen, it directly goes from importing the bus to the wrappers.

Jeepney is a pure Python interface to D-Bus, a protocol for interprocess communication on desktop Linux. It's interaction with wsl2 may get a bit funny if DISPLAY value is set, and that may have caused the issue. Works perfectly with DISPLAY value set to empty though.

Comment: I don't see how your answer is any different than the previous answer -- Your solution is the same -- Unset DISPLAY.  The problem isn't specific to Jeepney; it's a problem with `pip` attempting to use the keyring, which also uses `dbus`.  This should probably have been a comment on the existing answer once you have enough rep.