# Python3 on WSL 2 takes forever (over 6 minutes) to import keyring

Tags: python, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dbus, python-keyring

I noticed this issue when trying to run `pip` commands on my `WSL2` `Ubuntu-20.04` machine that it would take a long time to run anything. I finally narrowed it down to when `pip` is importing the `keyring` module.

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, May 27 2021, 13:30:53)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> def import_keyring():
...     time_start = time.time()
...     import keyring
...     print(f"Keyring took {time.time() - time_start} seconds to load")
...
>>> import_keyring()
Keyring took 400.4930064678192 seconds to load
```

looking at the process explorer, it seems there is a child process that it is waiting for:

```
 dbus-launch --autolaunch <32 character hex string> --binary-syntax --close-stderr
```

the dbus-launch command itself does not seem to have any child processes, so I used `strace` to see where it's hanging:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(6000), sin_addr=inet_addr("<my main machine's IP>")}, 16) = 0
```

It looks to be trying to connect to the host windows computer on port 6000 and failing? Now I'm just at a loss of what is happening and why it's taking so long to fail. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this ready to ask when finally clicked on what port `6000` meant. I tried setting up X server on Windows for `WSL2` to use a long time ago.

Either get the X server working or unset your `DISPLAY` environment variable and this should clear it right up.

```
export DISPLAY=
```

Hope this helps anyone else running into this obscure issues!

Comment: This is a great example of answering your own question (and also a well-written question), but please also consider if it would be better on https://superuser.com.

Comment: The problem [has been fixed](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/issues/531). So updating `keyring` should help (`pip install -U keyring`).