# WSL2 - pip install takes a long time (around 4 minutes to complete)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, windows-10, wsl-2

I just activated WSL2 on Windows 10. I already activated virtualenv to install django using `pip install django`.

But it takes around 4 minutes to complete the installation.

Is it normal for WSL2 to takes that long time only pip packages?

Any tweaks to speed up `pip install` on WSL2?

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: I’m using WSL and pip works fast enough for me. Depending on the environment, some packages don’t have *whl files and therefore are compiled from source. It may take a lot of time.

Comment: I'm on mobile at the moment, but I think we have the answer to this in a question already.  Try unsetting the `DISPLAY` variable and see if that fixes it.  If not, I'll dig further when I get back to my desk and see if I can find the previous question/answer on this.  It's related to pip trying to use the gnome keyring if it finds `DISPLAY` iirc.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I tried to unsetting the `DISPLAY` like on https://stackoverflow.com/a/69011437/2512500 but still have similar result around 4-5 minutes on WSL